# Delphi XE4 iOS Loading bitmap - no file loaded

Tags: ios, delphi, bitmap, delphi-xe4

My XE4 app runs fine on win but fails to load a bitmap in iOS. The file does exist (have checked in a terminal window) and the Findfirst stuff finds it. I get no exception in iOS but if the file doesn't exist in win I get an exception, hence the 'IsEmpty' check which retruns true in iOS.

So, any clues as to why it's not loading a file that exists and not raising an exception?

Cheers.

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  if FindFirst('.\*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  repeat
    showmessage(SR.Name);
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  FindClose(SR);

  imgImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('.\'+'myfile.gif');

{$ELSE}
  if FindFirst(GetHomePath + PathDelim + Application.Title + '.app' + PathDelim+'*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  repeat
    showmessage(SR.Name);
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  FindClose(SR);

  imgImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(GetHomePath + PathDelim + Application.Title + '.app' + PathDelim + 'myfile.gif');

{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did some debugging into the delphi units and it appears that on iOS gif isn't supported. This may well be a bug, but answers my question!